# boost::mutex::scoped_lock has been used and It sometimes throws the exception

Tags: c++, boost, locking, mutex, boost-thread

I am using scoped_lock in my multithread code to exclusively access to some part of code, but **sometimes** it throws to the exception *Access violation writing location ...*.

```
boost::mutex mMutex;    
boost::condition mInputQueueNotEmpty;    
Job* MyThreadPool<Job, JobOutput>::GetNextJob()  
{    
    boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(mMutex);

    while (mInputQueue.empty())
        mInputQueueNotEmpty.wait(lock);

    // Do something ...
}
```

I traced the code and I found out that there is a variable active_count in basic_timed_mutex class and whenever the runtime error happens, this variable is uninitialized.
runtime error happens around here:

```
bool try_lock()
{
    return !win32::interlocked_bit_test_and_set(&active_count,lock_flag_bit);
}
```

I do not know what should I do! because I do not have access to this variable and I am not responsible for initializing it.

**UPDATE**

the class of my function is this:

```
#pragma once

#include <vector.h>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include "MyThread.h"
#include <queue>
#include <boost/thread/condition.hpp>

template <class Job, class JobOutput>
class MyThreadPool
{
public:
    MyThreadPool(int processJobWhenArrived);        
    virtual ~MyThreadPool(void);
        void    Initialize(int ThreadsCount);
        void    AddJob(Job* job);
        void    StartProcess();
        Job*    GetNextJob();
    virtual void    FinishJob(Job* job, JobOutput* jobOutput);
        void    WaitUntilAllJobsProcessed();

public:
    vector<MyThread<Job, JobOutput>*> mThreads;

    queue<Job*> mInputQueue;
    queue<pair<Job*,JobOutput*>> mOutputQueue;

    boost::mutex        mMutexAdd;
    boost::mutex        mMutex;
    boost::condition    mInputQueueNotEmpty;
    boost::mutex        mJobOutputMutex;
    boost::mutex        mJobsMutex;
    boost::condition    mProcessJobs;
    bool            mStartProcessJobs;
    int         mJobsInputCount;
    int         mJobsOutputCount;
    int         mPrevJobsOutputCount;
    bool            mProcessJobWhenArrived;
};

template <class Job, class JobOutput>
void MyThreadPool<Job, JobOutput>::Initialize(int threadsCount)
{
    mStartProcessJobs = false;
    for (int t = 0; t < threadsCount; t++)
        mThreads.push_back(new MyThread<Job, JobOutput>(this));
}

template <class Job, class JobOutput>
void MyThreadPool<Job, JobOutput>::AddJob(Job* job)
{
    boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(mMutexAdd);
    mInputQueue.push(job);
    mJobsInputCount++;

    if (mProcessJobWhenArrived)
        mInputQueueNotEmpty.notify_all();
}

template <class Job, class JobOutput>
Job* MyThreadPool<Job, JobOutput>::GetNextJob()
{
    boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(mMutex);

    if (mInputQueue.empty() && mStartProcessJobs && mJobsInputCount == mJobsOutputCount)
        mProcessJobs.notify_one();

    while (mInputQueue.empty())
        mInputQueueNotEmpty.wait(lock);

    Job* job = mInputQueue.front();
    mInputQueue.pop();

    return job;
}
```

and this is the code where I use GetNextJob function:

```
#pragma once

#include <MyMemory.h>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>

template <class Job, class JobOutput>
class MyThreadPool;

template <class Job, class JobOutput>
class MyThread
{           
public:
    static void StaticRun(MyThread* p);
    void Run();

public:
    boost::thread   mThread;            
    MyThreadPool<Job, JobOutput>*   mThreadPool;            
};

#include "MyThreadPool.h"
template <class Job, class JobOutput>
MyThread<Job, JobOutput>::MyThread(MyThreadPool<Job, JobOutput>* threadPool)
{
    mThread = boost::thread(StaticRun, this);
    mThreadPool = threadPool;
}

template <class Job, class JobOutput>
void MyThread<Job, JobOutput>::StaticRun(MyThread* p)
{
    p->Run(); 
}

template <class Job, class JobOutput>
void MyThread<Job, JobOutput>::Run()
{
    JobOutput   *jobOutput;
    while (true)
    {
        Job* job = mThreadPool->GetNextJob();
        jobOutput = Process (job);
        mThreadPool->FinishJob(job, jobOutput);
    }

}
```

there is a class that inhrerits MyThreadPool

```
class SsThreadPool : public MyThreadPool<Job, JobOutput>
```

and this is where threadPool has been used:

```
class BPS
{
    //...
    SsThreadPool            mJobsThreadPool;
    //...
}
void    BPS::Initialize()
{
    mJobsThreadPool.Initialize(mConcurrentThreadsCount);
}

void    BPS::f()
{
    //...
    for (int i = 0; i < jobsCount; i++)
    {
        //...
        mJobsThreadPool.AddJob(job);
        //...

    }
    mJobsThreadPool.StartProcess(); 
    mJobsThreadPool.WaitUntilAllJobsProcessed();
    //...
}
```

Comment: Is this the actual code for which you are getting an access violation?

Comment: is `mMutex` a global variable? Are you trying to access it from the constructor of the other global object?

Comment: Yes, I get exception at this line: `boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(mMutex);`

Comment: @aleguna `mMutex` is not a global variable, it's a non-static member of a class and I just access it from a function of its class.

Comment: Post the real code then. I'm 99.99% sure problem is in it and not in boost.

Comment: @aleguna I've just added some part of my class code to my post.

Comment: Now post the code the uses it as well

Comment: @aleguna I've done it.

Comment: we are almost there ) Where `threadPool` comes from?

Comment: @aleguna I've added the codes that uses threadPool.

Comment: you still haven't shown how you initialize `MyThread` and `BPS`

Comment: @aleguna I initialize `MyThread` in the initialize function of `MyThreadPool`.

Answer (score 2):

It raises access violation, because you attempt to lock a destroyed `mutex`. Since the mutex is a member of your class, it means your code attempts to access a member-function of a destroyed instance ("dangling pointer"). To debug this case, put a breakpoint in `~MyThreadPool` and see when it gets called.

Comment: as you said, I put breakpoint in `~MyThreadPool` but access violation raises before calling the destructor.

Comment: @Samaneh Saadat Ok, I see. Another option (much worse) is a heap corruption that "overwrites" some part of `mMutex`. Anyway, something ruins the mutex object. BTW, what boost version are you using?

Comment: I use boost 1.47.0 to immediate handling the error I defined `mMutex` within `GetNextJob` method, after this modification access violation raises near next line and now it has problem with `mInputQueue`.

Comment: @Samaneh Saadat defining `mMutex` locally defeats its purpose (it should be shared between threads), but the fact that the next object member gets affected now just confirms my hypothesis: you definitely have a heap corruption that ruins `MyThreadPool` instance members. Try taking look at the functions being called prior to this crash.

Comment: @Samaneh Saadat and of course, it's worth upgrading boost (without regards to this particular crash):  http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/thread/changes.html

Comment: I think you're right and I probably have a heap corruption. but I couldn't solve the problem by looking at call stack.

Comment: @Samaneh Saadat call-stack at the point of crash wouldn't help you. You should inspect the functions that usually get invoked *prior* to this point. Especially, pay attention to unsafe type-casts, calling operator `delete` instead of `delete[]`,  pointer arithmetics, inheriting non-virtual destructors. Enable all the possible runtime checks in MSVC, use debug heap (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/974tc9t1(v=vs.100).aspx). Google "c++ debugging heap corruption".

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the object,that is holding the mutex, gets destroyed and then someone is trying to access the mutex. possible in your code ?

Comment: I don't think so. lifetime of that object is as long as the program's lifetime.